# What do these game durations mean?

Tags: time-control

There are different game duration on chess.com. What do options 1|1, 2|1 etc. mean?

[image: games]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For example 3|2 means each player starts with 3 minutes and gets 2 seconds added to the clock for making a move (this is called an "increment").

When there is no "|", you do not get any time for making a move, and each player gets the displayed time in minutes at the start of the game.

Another notation you might see uses a "+", for example 3+2.

Comment: ah, that is why coudn't see a great difference between 1 min and 1|1. I noticed that the clock turns back to 1:00 during the first moves but after that it seemed the same as "1 min".

Comment: Sometimes the clock will be capped at the starting time.  So, even if the time is 3min+5seconds, and you make each move in 1 second, you can’t get more than 3 minutes on the clock.

Comment: Another kind of time control, though I don't know how common it is for on-line play, includes a "delay".  If a time control is 30 minutes with a 5-second delay, that would mean that a player's clock won't start running until five seconds after the opponent's move, but moves that take less than 5 seconds won't build up time on the clock.

Comment: @supercat It's the standard time control in Shogi - including online Shogi - but I've never seen it in (Western) chess.

Comment: @adam-chalcraft - delay time controls are common in US Chess Federation over-the-board play.  A closely related type of time control is the "Bronstein delay", where a player's clock starts running as soon as they're on move, and the delay time is added back when the player presses the clock - but the add-back can never increase the available time.  So, if there's a 5 second Bronstein delay, but the player only uses 2 seconds for their move, they only get 2 seconds added back, and they end up with the same amount of time on the clock as they started with.